# How to implement iOS type ON SWIPE DELETE feature using ONSEN-UI in PhoneGap Application?

Tags: jquery, ios, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I am developing PhoneGap allication using ONSEN-UI for my personal usage. Now I have multiple ons-list-items on my one page like the ListView. I want to implement iOS type feature that is if I swipe List Item to Left or write, it will ask me to delete the List Item and by confirming, it will delete that List Item.

```
                           **OR**
```

If that is not possible, then I take one EDIT Button on that page and by clicking on that Button, another DELETE button will be slide out from left or right in all the List Items. By clicking on one particular DELETE button, that List Item will be deleted.

So how to get this functionality? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<ons-carousel>` inside an `<ons-list-item>` to achieve this effect.

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item style="padding: 0" ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
        <ons-carousel style="height: 44px; width: 100%" swipeable initial-index="1" auto-scroll>
          <ons-carousel-item>
            <a href="#">Delete</a>
          </ons-carousel-item>
          <ons-carousel-item>
            Item {{ item }}
          </ons-carousel-item>
        </ons-carousel>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

Please see this Codepen for a working example:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/YPmjwm